# NSMutableURLRequest loses session information

Tags: iphone, ios, session, nsurlrequest, nsmutableurlrequest

I have an iphone app that I'm trying to get to talk to a rails back end.  I'm using NSMutableURLRequest to pull data back and forth.  All the calls work fine on GET requests but when I need to post data, my rails app can't seem to find the session.  I've posted the code below for both a get and a POST request.

This is the POST request:

```
//Set up the URL
NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://testserver.example.com/players.xml"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                     timeoutInterval:30];

//To create an object in rails
//We have to use a post request
////This is the format when using xml
NSString *requestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<player><team_game_id>%@</team_game_id><person_id>%@</person_id></player>", game, person];


NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[requestString UTF8String] length:[requestString length]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

//For some reason rails will not take application/xml
[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
```

The get request is:

```
NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://testserver.example.com/people/find_by_passport?passport=%i", passport];
passportString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i", passport];
NSLog(@"The passport string is %@", passportString);

NSLog(url_string, nil);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData 
                                     timeoutInterval:30];
```

I am at my wits end here trying to find out whats going on so any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue. Parse the response headers for the Set-Cookie header, extract the cookies by hand, pass them back as `Cookie:` header on subsequent requests.

If this is just about sessions in their simplest, you don't have to worry about persistence, HTTPS, domains/paths and such.

EDIT: I found class NSHTTPCookieStorage. See if it can be of help...

Comment: So I somewhat understand what I'm trying to do here, but I'm feeling like I'm missing something, I pulled the Set-Cookie out into a string, stored that in a keychain item, picked it back up on the next request and added it to the http header field.  Is this all I need to do, what do you meean by "extract the cookies by hand"?

Comment: Actually I found the same thing and I tried adding the cookie back to that header but it doesn't seem to be helping me any..